# Precisely detect the boarder of an irregular-shape widget in flutter

Tags: web, flutter, flutter-layout, shapes, flutter-web

Flutter + Web

Hello, community. I encountered this problem while trying to write a region detection functionality to let the user select their state from a country map.  [image: Map example]
As shown in the Australia map, desired outcome is when the user clicks 'area A', South Australia will be selected instead of Queensland.

Want to know if there is such a widget helps to achieve this.

Appreciate in advance!!

Comment: are you using some svg vectors for state borders?

Comment: What kind of widgets are you using to display the map?

Comment: I have both .svg and .png assets. But I assume in this case .svg is the one to use?

Comment: Are you using a canvas for this? e.g custom painter?